# Pre-populate record with values from previous record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Ruby on Rails app I'm working on I have a Model that belongs_to a User.  The User can create many of these.

When a user goes to the new action, I want to prepopulate the values with the values from the last record they created.  These can then be changed if desired and used to create a new record.

I'm assuming that in the new action of my controller, I can get the most recent record (using something like this).

```
Model.first(:order => "created_at DESC")
```

Once I have that, how can I use it to pre-populate the record I created with the new method?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just initialize the attr?

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize_some_attr
    Model.first(:order => "created_at DESC").some_attr
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do that, I was hoping there was a way to do it all at once. Like maybe just getting Model.first and clearing out the id or something.  I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails, so I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: Seems like it is doing it all at once the only thing you need to do is Model.create ??

Answer (score 0):

```
r = Model.first(:order => "created_at DESC")
n = Model.new(r.attributes)
```